# Remove atmost K subtrees

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees

Given a tree with N vertices numbered from 1 to N.

The vertex 1 is the root of the tree. Each vertex is assigned with an integer weight. A remove operation can remove sub-tree rooted at an arbitrary vertex u. We must use at most K remove operations (possibly zero) so that the total weight of the remaining vertices is largest.

We need to tell the largest total weight of the remaining vertices.

**Example :** Let N=5 and K=2 and weights of all 5 nodes are : [1,1,-1,-1,-1].

Also Let N-1 edges are as follow :

```
1 2
2 3
4 1
4 5
```

Then here answer is 2.

**Explanation :** We use 2 remove operations: one for the sub-tree rooted at 3 and the other one for the sub-tree rooted at 4. There are only 2 remaining vertices which are 1 and 2. The total weight is 1+1=2.

**My Approach :** Keep weight of its sub tree at each Node of the tree and delete the one with minimum weight.But how to update the weight of remaining tree is one of the problem.Also what is efficient way to store the weight of sub tree at each Node.Any Help Please ?

Comment: You would help readers and yourself by explaning at the beginning that
some weights are negative and that they are the only one you may want
to remove. Hence, when deleting subtrees, you do not want simply to `delete
the one with minimum weight`, but only those with minimum *negative* weight.

Comment: @babou But if in that subtree weight is minimum and it contains negative nodes as well as positive nodes then we will delete those nodes also

Comment: Yes, but the total weight of the subtree must be negative, if it is a
candidate for removal. Furthermore, I am afraid that greedy approach
is not optimal. Consider a subtree with negative weight having a leaf
with weight 0. Replace that leaf with weight 0 with a leaf that has
negative weight less than the weight of any subtree. What does your
approach do? The subtree weight can be stored exactly like the node
weight. No problem there. Updating the weight of the remaining tree is
based on two properties called associativity and commutativity of
addition.

Comment: Please edit your question to ask a specific question.  "Any Help Please?" is not a specific question.  This is not the place to copy-paste your programming exercise and have us solve it for you.  If your question is how to update the weights when you remove one subtree, ask that.  (But that is very easy; if you can't answer that, you are probably  going to find it very difficult to solve this problem, and you would be better off practicing with some more basic problems first to build your data structure  and algorithm design skills.)